# How can I get text that's not within a htlm tag?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

```
<div class="subbold">
   <span id="MainContentPlaceHolder_properties_lblBed_0">1</span>"

   Bed, 1 Bath

   "<span id="MainContentPlaceHolder_properties_PropertyType_1">1</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get "Bed, 1 Bath".

`//div[contains(@class, 'subbold')]/text()` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

`//div[contains(@class, 'subbold')]/*[1]/following-sibling::text())`

`/*[1]` gets that first child of the div tag which is the span tag. Then `following-sibling::text()` gets what's right next to it, which is the tagless text.

`//div[contains(@class, 'subbold')]/*[2]` does not get the tagless text for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use [Xpath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp). So you should get the text using this:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'subbold')]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()
```

or

```
//span[@id='MainContentPlaceHolder_properties_lblBed_0']/following-sibling::text()
```